# Where Condition on Eloquent Model laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to query tables using the eloquent relation. but I am not able to run the one below.

```
$categorylisting=Listing::with('listingimages','listingprice','listingcountry','listingstate','listingcity','listingcapacity')
                ->where('listing_type',$listingtype)
                ->where('state',$states)
                ->where('city',$city)
                ->where('min_pax','>=',$paxrange)
                ->paginate(10);
```

I get below error when I try to run the above.`min_pax` is a column in `listing_capacity`  table.

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'min_pax' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `listings` where `listing_type` = 1 and `state` = 2434 and `city` = 1918915 and `min_pax` >= 25)
```

Comment: Use [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Comment: is `min_pax` a column of `listings` ?

Comment: No, its a column in listing_capacity table